# Asynchronous call that updates db

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a kendogrid with an editable textbox on each row.  Textboxes are autofilled with data from db upon load.

I would like to asynchronously save any changes made to the textboxes. right now im unable to even access my textboxes on input....

Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<DTOFacility>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tbody > tr > td > div.col-xs-s > :text').on('propertychange input', function (e) {
            console.log('first' + $(this).val());
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="Screen">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "GridForm" }))
    {
        <div id="SystemPreferences">
            <div class="panel panel-primary ">
                <div class="panel-heading col-xs-12 clearfix">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h2 class="pull-left mt5">Grid</h2>

                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="panel-action-bar">
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DTOFacility>()
                              .Name("Grid")
                              .Columns(columns =>
                                  {
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.Facility);
                                      columns.Bound(e => e.Number)
                                             .ClientTemplate(
                                                 @"<div class='col-xs-2'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='codebox' value='#= value #' maxlength='3'/></div> "
                                          );
                                  })
                              .Pageable(pager => pager.Messages(Info => Info.Empty("No Results Found")))
                              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow-y: hidden;" })
                              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                            .Ajax()
                                                            .PageSize(6)
                                                            .Read(read => read.Action("Data", "MyController"))
                              )
                              )
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Markup:

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">

<tr data-uid="27c8a881-1d6b-4e0b-b897-c6b04a185cd6" role="row">
<td role="gridcell">Facility  1</td>
<td role="gridcell"><div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="codebox" value="BGG" maxlength="3"></div>
</td></tr>

<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="5ed6cee8-9365-42db-b711-f2aaa2c69adf" role="row">
<td role="gridcell">Facility 2</td>
<td role="gridcell"><div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="codebox" value="ABC" maxlength="3"></div> 
</td></tr>

<tr data-uid="da8ba253-0fc0-4dc7-a110-7b4bda6b8a35" role="row">
<td role="gridcell">Facility 3</td>
<td role="gridcell"><div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="codebox" value="DEF" maxlength="3"></div>
</td></tr>

<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="36d2e72f-b3cb-4dd6-8fd3-f62f3a5a26e7" role="row">
<td role="gridcell">Facility 4</td>
<td role="gridcell"><div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="codebox" value="GHI" maxlength="3"></div> 
</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use AJAX in jQuery?  It's not really clear where you're stuck.

Comment: I'm unable to get my jquery code to work.  It isn't finding the textboxes.  But more insight as to how to do the async call would be nice afterwards. Baby steps.

Comment: Well, what is the markup that this jQuery is targeting?  When that selector runs, do any matching elements exist?

Comment: It's trying to target the textbox repeating on each row iwithin the kendogrid.  Do you want em to copy/paste my html markup from chrome dev tools?

Comment: Well, since the selector is targeting a *very specific* hierarchy of elements, it's *probably* a good idea to at least look at the HTML and see if those elements exist.  It's also worth debugging to see if those elements exist *when that code runs* rather than being dynamically created afterward.

Comment: My selector is based off the markup i saw.  I thought that was painfully obvious.

Comment: No need to downvote because you can't answer the question @David

Comment: What exactly is the question?  So far the question itself is basically, "How do I use AJAX?"  Which is too broad.  And in the comments you claim that your jQuery selector isn't finding the intended elements, but for some reason you don't want to show the HTML.  We're just meant to trust that it's "painfully obvious" that you wrote the selector correctly.  So what question are you actually asking?  I'd like to help, but currently there isn't an answerable question here.

Comment: I literally asked you if you wanted to see the html markup code.... " Do you want em to copy/paste my html markup from chrome dev tools? "  I never once said I wouldnt do it.  I looked at it and don't know why I can't get the textbox which is why I'm here....

Comment: You have a typo in your selector.  Change the class on the `div` to match the markup and it works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/9aeeg0hb/

Comment: Good catch but it still doesnt work.  I have no idea why anymore.

Comment: The markup in the jsFiddle is unedited (except for indentation), so the selector itself demonstrably works.  Perhaps the elements are being generated more dynamically than expected?  Do they exist when the document's ready event fires?  Try putting in some debugging statements around that jQuery to see what's going on at runtime.  (Noting that a breakpoint alone might not reveal the desired information because the "dynamic" stuff may happen within milliseconds while the debugger is otherwise paused.)

Comment: Its pulling data and inserting into the grid.  If it were firing the jquery before the data is loaded, how would i fix that?  I already have the jquery at the bottom of the view

Comment: This somehow worksm but is not what i want..... $('tbody').on('propertychange input', function () {
        $("tbody .form-control").each(function () {
            console.log($(this));
        });
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[After some back and forth in the comments above, something "answer"-worthy may be emerging...]

> Its pulling data and inserting into the grid. If it were firing the jquery before the data is loaded, how would i fix that? I already have the jquery at the bottom of the view.

Therein appears to be the rub.  The jQuery code in the question executes when the document loads, but it would appear that very quickly *after* the document loads, the Kendo grid makes its AJAX request to actually get the data and populate the grid.

So I see two potential options...

Perhaps Kendo has some event or callback you can invoke after their asynchronous operation completes?  I don't know the product well enough to demonstrate, but I suspect the product is mature enough to have something like that.

As an alternative, you can make use of `.on()` with a higher-level DOM element to catch the events of dynamically created elements.  Something like this might work:

```
$(document).on('propertychange input', 'tbody > tr > td > div.col-xs-2 > :text', function (e) {
    // ...
});
```

Note that the handler is attached to the `document` itself, which most certainly does exist when the document loads.  (Technically it can be attached to any non-changing element in the hierarchy between the target element(s) and the top level.)  And it just filters the events based on the selector.